# how to find the next td element type using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<tr>
<td class="value" style="width:40%;">
<label class="label">Gender value</label>
</td>
<td class="value" style="width:40%;">
<input id="checkbox" type="checkbox" tabindex="0" name="chkCustom">
<label>M</label>
<input id="checkbox" type="checkbox" tabindex="0" name="chkCustom">
<label>F</label>
<input id="checkbox" type="checkbox" tabindex="0" name="chkCustom">
<label>U</label>
</td>
</tr>
```

I have the above HTML, I am reading all the controls from my webpage dynamically. In above I want to read the label value to its specified type and read the next value on the basis of its type:

Please look on my code:

```
     // Read labels text
        $("#tblCustomFields tr .label").each(function () {
            var value = this.innerHTML;
            console.log(this);
            var type = $(this).closest('td').next().find('input').val();
            alert(value);
            alert(type);
   //If next element type is *checkbox* then read checkbox values
        if(type == "checkbox")
        {

     // Read checkbox values

    $('tblCustomFields tr input:checked').each(function (s) {
        var inputCheckBox = new Array();
        inputCheckBox.push([this.id, 0]);
    });

    for (var i = 0; i < inputCheckBox.length; i++) {
        alert(inputCheckBox[i]);
    }
    }
    });
```

The above code will give me all the checkboxes on the webpage but I want the checkboxes only defined in the above HTML, and I also want to read the values of only those checkboxes which are checked.  Please help.

**GOAL:** I am binding the dynamic HTML to the page its type might be **checkbox** or **dropdown** or **text**. Now I want to read the page labels and the values related to that labels. For ex my label(**Gender value**) has values of type **checkbox** so I just want to read the checked checkbox values related to that label.

**UPDATE:** At least tell me that how can I get the next element type

I am using the below code:

```
 var type = $(this).closest('td').next().find('type').val();
```

**ANY HELP**

Comment: add a # to tblCustomFields when you read checkbox values

Comment: Is the goal to simply read the values of all the checked checkboxes? I think you might be over-complicating things.

Comment: I have updated my goal.please check

Comment: Why you don't assign a class to your elements then read them using `$(".my-checkboxes")` or using `data` attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that all the markup has to be reviewed, but anyway, I think I know (please notice me if don't) what you want.

Try this:

```
// Read labels text
        $("#tblCustomFields tr .label").each(function () {
            var value = this.innerHTML;
            console.log(this);
            alert(value);
            var inputCheckBox = new Array();
            $(this).first().closest("td").next().find("input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function(){
                inputCheckBox.push($(this).next("label").text());
            });

    for (var i = 0; i < inputCheckBox.length; i++) {
        alert(inputCheckBox[i]);
    }
    });
```

I'll make you a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/frikinside/WCf8P/2/) to test it.

Comment: Thanks, can you please tell me how can I read the values input of type "text" and "ddl"

Comment: I'd make an update to the jsFiddle to use input text and selects. If you use "value" attibute in the checkboxes, the script could be a lot handy, and you would no have to handle each type. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/frikinside/WCf8P/2/)

Comment: I am using the below code:

$(this).first().closest("td").next().find("input[value='Please Select'] option:selected").val()

Comment: I update the jsFiddle of the answer. It should be pointing to the right code. Just a question for your last comment, why yopu would find an input with some value to obtain the value? I mean, you look for an input with a value of `Please Select` and then, you get value with `.val()` I don't know what the purpose is

Answer (score 0):

Your question is confusing.

$("#tblCustomFields tr .label") - This will look for a child of TR with class **label**. Your HTML, shows that this resides inside **td**. If all the label elements have class label, you can refer each by -

```
$(".label).each(function(){
//do whatever you want  
});
```

To get the element type next to the label with class label -

```
$(".label).each(function(){
 var NextTd  = $(this).parent().next(); // refers to the next td
  $(NextTd).each(function(){
    var type = $(this).find('input').prop('tagName');
//do whatever you want  
});
});
```